# FANUC KAREL XML parser

Tags: xml, parsing, karel

maybe here is someone who knows FANUC KAREL a little bit.
I have to create a XML parser, to get specific parts of a telegram.

I started with the FANUC template code, but currently I get no results. Nothing.

Here you can see the message, I have to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<message><name>Run.Locate.Ok</name><job>1</job><match>1</match><matches>1</matches><x>90.735872311523</x><y>-5.0591040552784</y><z>0</z><rx>0</rx><ry>0</ry><rz>166.37113177833</rz><px>90.735872311523</px><py>-5.0591040552784</py><pz>0</pz><prx>0</prx><pry>0</pry><prz>166.37113177833</prz><scale>1.0</scale><score>97.627884149551</score><time>134</time><exposure>1</exposure><identified>1</identified></message>
```

And here you can see my current KAREL source:

```
PROGRAM xmlparse
%NOLOCKGROUP
%NOPAUSESHFT
%NOPAUSE = ERROR + COMMAND + TPENABLE
%NOABORT = ERROR + COMMAND
%ENVIRONMENT xml
%include klerxmlf

CONST
    MYXML_CONST = 3

TYPE
    xmlstrct_t = STRUCTURE
        first   :   integer
        second  :   real
        third   :   boolean
        fourth  :   string[20]
    ENDSTRUCTURE

-- Local Vars
VAR
    xml_result  :   file
    status      :   INTEGER
    tag_name    :   string[32]
    attrnames   :   array[32] of string[32]
    attrvalues  :   array[32] of string[64]
    text        :   array[32] of String[128]
    xmlstrct    :   xmlstrct_t
    tag_ident   :   integer
    textdone    :   boolean
    func_code   :   integer
    text_idx    :   integer
    numattr     :   integer
    done        :   boolean 
    startdata   :   boolean
    xmlp_done   :   boolean


Routine xml_parse:boolean

BEGIN   
    -- Parse XML Data
    SET_FILE_ATR(xml_result, ATR_XML)
    CLR_IO_STAT(xml_result)
    WRITE TPDISPLAY('XML_Start',CR)
    OPEN FILE xml_result('RO','MC:\result.xml')

    WRITE TPDISPLAY('File OK',CR)
    status = IO_STATUS(xml_result)
    WRITE TPDISPLAY('Status 1',CR)
    IF (status <> 0) THEN
        POST_ERR(status, '', 0, 0)
        abort
    ENDIF
    WRITE TPDISPLAY('Status 2',CR)
    xml_addtag (xml_result, 'xmlstrct_t', 32, FALSE, MYXML_CONST, status)
    WRITE TPDISPLAY('Status 3',CR)
    textdone = TRUE
    done = FALSE
    startdata = FALSE
    while (done = FALSE) DO
        xml_scan(xml_result,'message',tag_ident,func_code,status)
        WRITE TPDISPLAY('Status 4',CR)
        if (status = 0) THEN
            done = TRUE
        ENDIF
        IF (status = XML_FUNCTION) THEN
            Status = 0
            SELECT tag_ident of
                Case (MYXML_CONST) :
                    SELECT func_code of
                        Case (XML_START) :
                            text_idx = 1
                            xml_setvar (xml_result, 'message', 'xmlstrct', status)
                            xml_getdata(xml_result, numattr, attrnames, attrvalues, text[text_idx], textdone, status)
                        Case (XML_END) :
                            IF (startdata = TRUE) THEN
                                startdata = FALSE
                            ELSE
                                text_idx = 1
                                xml_setvar (xml_result, 'message', 'xmlstrct', status)
                                xml_getdata(xml_result, numattr, attrnames, attrvalues, text[text_idx], textdone, status)
                            ENDIF
                        Case (XML_TXCONT) :
                                text_idx = text_idx + 1
                                xml_getdata (xml_result, numattr, attrnames, attrvalues, text[text_idx], textdone, status)
                        ELSE:
                    ENDSELECT
                ELSE:
            ENDSELECT
        ELSE
            IF (status <> XML_SCANLIM) THEN
                POST_ERR(status, '', 0, 0)
                done = TRUE
            ENDIF
        ENDIF
    ENDWHILE
    WRITE TPDISPLAY('Status 5',CR)

    xml_remtag(xml_result, 'xmlstrct_t', status)
    close file xml_result
    status = IO_STATUS(xml_result)
    IF (status <> 0) THEN
        POST_ERR(status, '', 0, 0)
        xmlp_done = FALSE
    ELSE
        xmlp_done = TRUE
    ENDIF

    WRITE TPDISPLAY('File Closed 3',CR)
    RETURN (xmlp_done)

END xml_parse

Begin
END xmlparse
```

What I need is the seperated Tag contents, like the position.

Can anybody give me some brain input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FANUC Karel manual is definitely unclear about the XML functions. I wrote a Karel XML parser only once, 5 years ago, so I cannot be as accurate as I would, but I clearly remember a few hints that may help you.

For first, try a one line XML file and write a specific Karel program for it, it will help you a lot in understanding how Karel works.

Keep in mind that a **STRUCTURE** should describe exactly the same type and quantity of data that the XML tags will contain: the structure of the manual example is made for an XML approx made like

```
<data>
    <first>5</second>
    <second>5.5</second>
    <third>1</third>
    <fourth>some text here</forth>
</data>
```

In your case, let me format your XML:

```
<message>
    <name>Run.Locate.Ok</name>
    <job>1</job>
    <match>1</match>
    <matches>1</matches>
    <x>90.735872311523</x>
    <y>-5.0591040552784</y>
    <z>0</z>
    <rx>0</rx>
    <ry>0</ry>
    <rz>166.37113177833</rz>
    <px>90.735872311523</px>
    <py>-5.0591040552784</py>
    <pz>0</pz>
    <prx>0</prx>
    <pry>0</pry>
    <prz>166.37113177833</prz>
    <scale>1.0</scale>
    <score>97.627884149551</score>
    <time>134</time>
    <exposure>1</exposure>
    <identified>1</identified>
</message>
```

I'd rather go for a more pragmatic approach:

```
TYPE
    your_data = STRUCTURE
        name: STRING[64]
        job: INTEGER
        x: REAL
        -- All other things
    ENDSTRUCTURE
```

And than use directly the XML functions without the loops overheads.

A small hint: FANUC robots uses a 32 bit single precision representation for real numbers; if possible, I'd rather use a shorter representation for floats, otherwise the Karel program will heavily round the values and you may miss some relevant data.

Hope this helps, in case let me know that I can try to search my Karels.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I change now my code more and more. Your hint with 32 bit, I know this and this is not a problem. How you would write it short, without the loop? If you have time, I would be happy, when you can provide me your karel as example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be:

```
OPEN FILE xml_result('RO','MC:\result.xml')
```

Should be:

```
OPEN FILE xml_result('RW','MC:\result.xml')
```

RW instead of RO when opening the XML file